# How to replicate adding/mixing of HSV values in RGB space

Tags: math, image-processing, graphics, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

At the moment I'm doing a colourizing effect using additive blending in HSV space. Have a diff value in HSV space which is added to an image texture's individual pixels to get the desired color effect. But this is turning out to be expensive as the fragment shader has to do two costly conversions to do the addition

1. RGB -> HSV
2. HSV addition
3. HSV -> RGB

Is there a better way to do this? The diff value will be provided in HSV only. And the final color representation is in RGB to draw.

Many Thanks,

Sak

Comment: Well, how are you doing those conversions?

Comment: Standard conversion algorithm found on the internet, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#From_HSV    http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ncs/color/t_convert.html

Comment: There are many ways to implement these formulas, e.g. in terms of number of case distinctions. So there might be ways to increase performance there. I'm pretty unsure what meaning addition of hues could possibly have, though. I could understand that if you were to divide later on, to compute an average, but dividing hues does not make too much sense because the hue is only defined modulo 360°.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a similar effect to HSV manipulations by using a color matrix in RGB. For example, a rotation around the r=g=b axis is similar to a hue addition. (Adding x degrees in the hue channel is similar to a rotation of x degrees around r=g=b in RGB.) A translation along the r=g=b axis is similar to a value addition. (I believe that adding x to the value channel should be similar to adding x to all of r, g, and b.) And a uniform scale perpendicular to the r=g=b axis is similar to a saturation addition. I don't know off the top of my head the exact translation between adding x to saturation and scaling in RGB, but it shouldn't be too hard to work out. You should be able to compose these matrixes into a single matrix, and implement it as a single matrix multiply by the RGB value.

Comment: Thanks @user1118321 for the suggestion, Is there a reference for this concept? a working code will be really helpful.

Comment: There's a good example [on this website](http://www.graficaobscura.com/matrix/) and it even includes how to preserve luminance while doing a hue rotation.